# Como hacer que un numero baje constantemente en js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vscode

Estoy haciendo un proyecto en el que necesito tener un numero bajando continuamente,representa un pozo acumulado que desciende. He visto varios ejemplos con cuenta regresiva, pero yo necesitaria un numero entero que baje continuamente. Que argumentos le tengo que dar a la funcion para que muestre el decrecimiento?

```js
window.onload = cuenta;
var totalTime = 135000000;
function cuenta() {
  document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = totalTime;
  if(totalTime==0){
    alert('Final'); //aca necesitaria que en vez del alert resetee
  }else{
    totalTime-=1;
    setTimeout("cuenta()",1000);
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="contenedor" onclick="cambio()" >
    <div id="countdown"></div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-2">
        <img name="imagen" id="imagen1" alt="imagenes1" class="primera">
        <img name="imagen" id="imagen2" alt="imagenes2" class="primera">
        <img name="imagen" id="imagen3" alt="imagenes1" class="primera">
      </div>
    </div>
```

Graciasss :)

Comment: Tu pregunta es muy AMPLIA, necesitas que un numero "baje" con respecto a que? a un evento en especifico(click,etc..), en un determinado periodo de tiempo?, con un solo llamado de una función, ejecutando un ciclo (while. etc). Y sabes por que es muy AMPLIA? por que falta el contexto, el codigo para saber que estas haciendo y en que estas teniendo los inconvenientes. Aca te van a llenar de votos negativo y cerrar tu pregunta si no mejoras el formato.

Comment: Perdon! Es la primera vez que hago pregunta, soy bastante nueva aca y con js. Tiene un eventlistener a enter pero en realidad no tiene por que ir relacionado, sino simplemente aparecer como una cuenta regresiva.

`window.onload = cuenta;
var totalTime = 135000000;
function cuenta() {
document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = totalTime;
if(totalTime==0){
alert('Final'); //aca necesitaria que en vez del alert resetee
}else{
totalTime-=1;
setTimeout("cuenta()",1000);
}
}`

Comment: Y asi tengo el html, puse el id en un div dentro del contenedor principal, pero no me lo agarra, no se si lo puse en el lugar correcto :/

`<body>
    <div class="contenedor" onclick="cambio()" >
        <div id="countdown"></div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-2">
                <img name="imagen" id="imagen1" alt="imagenes1" class="primera">
                <img name="imagen" id="imagen2" alt="imagenes2" class="primera"> 
                <img name="imagen" id="imagen3" alt="imagenes1" class="primera">
                
            </div>
    </div>
`

Comment: Excelente, saber que tienes algo. Ahora solo te queda que le des [edit] a tu pregunta y agregues todo este código a la descripción de tu pregunta en lugar de los comentarios.

Comment: Genial, gracias! 

Comment: Viendo cómo funciona tu código (puedes verlo si le das al botón Ejecutar), no entiendo qué es lo que no pasa. Podrías editar de nuevo y aclarar mejor lo que no pasa y quieres que pase?

Answer (score 0):

Lo pude solucionar, les dejo el código como quedó por si a alguien le sirve:

```
window.onload = cuenta;


var tiempo = 10;

function cuenta() {
    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = tiempo;
    if(tiempo==0){
        tiempo = 15;
        cuenta();
    }else{
    tiempo-=1;
    setTimeout("cuenta()",200);
    }
    
}
`
```